# How do I redirect on same page while using window.location.href in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sms

```
<script>    
    $(document).on('click','.send_sms',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        phone = this.id;
        var IndNum = /^[0]?[789]\d{9}$/;
        if(IndNum.test(phone))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=**********&pass=**********&sender=*******&phone=**********&text=Testing&priority=ndnd&stype=normal",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(res) {
                    alert(res);
                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            alert('Mobile Number Not Valid');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am using bulk SMS gateway where I have a URL as I mention above in `window.location.href` where it working fine and sms sent successfully but I don't want to redirect. I want when I click on `send_sms` then it show only successful message. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Try this window.location.reload();

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: Have you tried anything or did some research on the problem? I would suggest AJAX to help you solve this problem. JQuery also has its implementation (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I had tried with ajax but not able to do @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Then you should post that code and give us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please check @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Was the call successful or did you get any errors in your developer console? What was the server response in the alert?

Comment: I am not getting alert @RenéBeneš

Comment: Then check the Network tab in developer console (usually F12) in you browser to check if request is being sent correctly. Also, use your parameters as properties of data object instead of query string.

Comment: Is the username and password now visible in the client? (script and network call). Doesn't seem like a secure solution.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you should send that request as a GET and not a POST? If you are, you might need to [url encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the values.